# JavaFX - ScrollPane content distorting issue on scroll

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I encountered a problem with the rendering of a JavaFX scrollpane. Sometimes when I scroll the pane, the contained view looks "teared" or simply missing certain details. The tearing can be fixed if the user changes the current focus in the application (i.e. by clicking a new element). Please see the image bellow.

[image: The scroll view, with tearing]

I made an example program that can replicate the issue:

```
public class ScrollingView extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Scrollview!");        
        ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane();
        root.paddingProperty().setValue( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();     

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            grid.addRow( i, createSpinner() );

        root.setContent(grid);
        root.vvalueProperty().addListener( (ov, oldV, newV) -> root. );

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node[] createSpinner(){
        Node[] nodes = new Node[2];

        nodes[0] = new Label("Spinner");

        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>();
        spinner.setEditable(false);
        IntegerSpinnerValueFactory spinnerFactory = new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 10, 5, 1);
        spinner.setValueFactory(spinnerFactory);    
        nodes[1] = spinner;

        return nodes;
    }
}
```

I googled the issue but couldn't come up with a solution. Does anyone know what causes the issue, and is there a way to fix it?

Thanks // Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the `Spinner` rendering distorts when the padding is applied to `ScrollPane`. Commenting out the

```
root.paddingProperty().setValue( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

resolves the issue. It may be a bug, and you would prefer to file it. Adding padding to another outer layout instead of ScrollPane ca be an option as workaround:

```
VBox vbox =new VBox(root);
vbox.setPadding( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox, 300, 150));
```

Comment: Wow, it was that simple. I've tried different things for days now but i never concidered that as a solution. Thanks for finding it!